# Django fixtures many to many with natural keys over multiple fields

Tags: django, django-fixtures, natural-key

I'm writing some additional fixtures for a project, and I have a question about how to use the natural keys.

In another fixture, the natural key for `area` is defined like so:

```
"fields": {
            "area": [
                "auckland",
                "NZ"
            ],
```

However, I'm writing a fixture for a model with a `ManyToMany` relation, so how do I include multiple two object keys? the following doesn't seem to work.

```
"fields": {
            "areas": [
                "auckland",
                "NZ",
                "sydney",
                "AUS"
            ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turns out its super straightforward:

```
"fields": {
            "areas": [
                [
                    "auckland",
                    "NZ",
                ],
                [
                    "sydney",
                    "AUS"
                ]
            ],
```